# How to use StringFormat in XAML elements?

Tags: xaml, string-formatting

I'm deep in a XAML stack of elements binding to orders.

The order date displays as e.g. "12/31/2008 12:00:00 AM".

**I want it to display as e.g. "31.12.2008".**

How can I do this? I have seen [other stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447035/what-is-the-wpf-xaml-data-binding-equivalent-of-string-format) mention StringFormat but they use multibinding in ways that I can't get to work.

Here is the kind of syntax I would like (this is pseudocode), simply specifying StringFormat where you need it, is this possible somehow?

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Header="Order ID" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderID}"
                    StringFormat="{}{1:dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Header="Order Date" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderDate}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think this should work:

```
<GridViewColumn
    Header="Order Date"
    DisplayMemberBinding=
        "{Binding Path=OrderDate, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
```

Comment: And you can append text on either side of the string, e.g. "Start Date: {0:dd-MM-yyyy}"

Comment: I had to take the single quotes off the StringFormat value.

Comment: Scratch that, I ultimately couldn't get my StringFormat to be honored and had to switch to ContentStringFormat.

Answer (score 29):

In general, you can look for an associated `*StringFormat` dependency property.  For example, all [ContentControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=net-5.0) implementations (such as Label and Tooltip) have the [ContentStringFormat dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat?view=net-5.0):

```
<Label
    Content="{Binding Path=DateAsked}"
    ContentStringFormat="{}{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}" />
```

In your case, while the [GridViewColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn?view=net-5.0) has the [HeaderStringFormat dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.headerstringformat?view=net-5.0) to go along with `Header`, there is no analog for the `DisplayMemberBinding` and so you will need .NET 3.5 SP1 (get it with [Visual Studio 2008 SP1](https://web.archive.org/web/20110605222632/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E)) or better to use the new [BindingBase.StringFormat Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=net-5.0):

```
<GridViewColumn 
    Header="Order ID"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderID, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"
/>
```

There are lots more examples at the blog post [Trying out Binding.StringFormat](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307210655/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx).

Comment: I like this one. Didn't even know about the ContentStringFormat.  Gives me some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <myNamespace:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<GridViewColumn 
DisplayMemberBinding=="{Binding Path=OrderDate, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}" 
/>
```

C#

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,
                       Type targetType,
                       object parameter,
                       CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return ((DateTime)value).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,
                              Type targetType,
                              object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since hours of searching how I get the `ConverterCulture={x:Static sysglb:CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture}}"`of other answers running, I ended with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to localize the date format, you can include it in your .resx file. You will have to set up your app for localization by following this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/.

The resx entry:

```
<data name="DateFormat" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>{0:dddd d MMMM H&#x3a;mm}</value>
</data>
```

In your content page, you then include the location of the resx file

```
xmlns:il8n="clr-namespace:MyProject.Localization;assembly=MyProject"
```

And then you can use it in your binding like so:

```
<Label
    Text = "{Binding Time, StringFormat={il8n:Translate DateFormat}}"
```