# How to remove 00:00:00 from DateTime property

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have `ListView` with `DateTime` field which displaying `00:00:00` on `Label`, that is not required at all.

```
public DateTime? StartDate
{
    get { return _startDate; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _startDate, value);
        //StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); NOT WORKING
    }
}
```

I tried to remove it using  below line but not working

```
StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //NOT WORKING
```

The code displaying it

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding StartDate}" />
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="To" />
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding EndDate}" />
</StackLayout>
```

ListCell:

[image]

How can I remove 0's from date:

Comment: You want to format it in display, not in value. You can use metadata like `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` above the property declaration

Comment: @Rafalon - Pl check my updated question.

Comment: Thank you, also check my updated comment ^^

Comment: Look at [String formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting) for Xamarin.Forms

Comment: date.ToShortDateString();   or date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); any of these method will work

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814176/how-to-format-date-and-time-in-xaml-in-xamarin-application, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685743/how-to-use-stringformat-in-xaml-elements, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447035/what-is-the-wpf-xaml-data-binding-equivalent-of-string-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how DateTime works in C#, let me give an example:

```cs
// This will print '01.01.2000 00:00:00'
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/1970", "dd/MM/yyy", CultureInfor.InvariantCulture));
```

This is expected, because every property in the DateTime struct has a value after the constructor, `00:00:00` is just the default value. What you need to do is format it where you're displaying it (so in your label), using `StringFormat` and a [format specifier for DateTime](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-essentials/0596000790/apcs02.html), the one you probably want is `d`. So your xaml should like this:

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="To" />
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to format the Binding on XAML

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsdata/2009/07/06/customize-format-of-datetime-string-in-wpf-and-winform-data-binding/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use StartDate.ToShortDateString() instead of StartDate.ToString(). ToShortDateString returns a string that contains the short date string representation of the current DateTime object.

Comment: `StartDate` will still be a `DateTime`, and will therefore still contain time information

Answer (score 0):

`date.ToString("d")` 
There are other formats but "d" is the short date. You need to change the output string, not the DateTime itself. The type DateTime contains the Date and the Time, as the name implies and removing the Time is not possible but you don't need to use the time.