# how to set number format for double type variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, string-formatting

This might be a very simple question.

How do I make sure that double will have number style in following format?

```
03.00, 02.04
```

if i Set

```
double foo=1;
```

variable **foo** should have number format 01.00.

if i set

```
foo = 2.5
```

it should have value `02.50`

**Implementaion** I have bound **foo** property to silverlight textbox through MVVM model.
I want to textbox to display number in **00.00** format always .

Comment: You should bind string to your text box, by double you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using silverlight version 4.0 check this tutorial

[Formatting made easy - Silverlight 4](http://geekswithblogs.net/PeterTweed/archive/2010/04/25/formatting-made-easy---silverlight-4.aspx)

You need to specify the string formate as shown in below example

```
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock5" 
        Text="{Binding DoubleValue, StringFormat='0,0.00'}" />
```

Also check : [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) on msdn

Comment: Yes its right I workd for me..<TextBox Text="{Binding Something, StringFormat=\{0:P\}}" />

Comment: My applcation is desinged for UK culture. So what i need string in **00,00** so i used 'StringFormat='0:00,00'' but its setting value like 0,000 why its so?

Comment: @pramod choudhari  - for that i think you can check this link may provide you more idea http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simple format for formating such value is:

```
string val = 1d.ToString("00.00");
```

I don't know if silverlight textbox have special property for value formatting, probably you neeed to convert it before.

**UPDATE**

You can use binding described here: [What is the WPF XAML Data Binding equivalent of String.Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447035/what-is-the-wpf-xaml-data-binding-equivalent-of-string-format)

Answer (score 0):

set the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) in your binding to "00.00" - if you show us your binding/xaml code I can give you more on that.

Comment: I have bound double type property to TextBox control. StringFormat will give me string type property.

Comment: no if you have used XAML and binding (WPF/Silverlight) you can set a StringFormat for that Bindding (from Silverlight 4 up) - if you use Silverlight 3 or bellow you have to use a ValueConverter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447035/what-is-the-wpf-xaml-data-binding-equivalent-of-string-format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringFormat` to format `Bindings` or use `Converters`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DoubleValue, StringFormat=StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" /> 

<TextBlock Text="{Binding DoubleValue, 
           Converter={StaticResource NumericFormatConverter}, 
           ConverterParameter=N2}" />
```